# DynamoDB Pagination, unknown error, exception or failure

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-sdk

I have a DynamoDB table that is generated with the following code:

```
const params = {
  TableName,
  AttributeDefinitions: [{
    AttributeName: 'post_id',
    AttributeType: 'S'
  }, {
    AttributeName: 'parent_post_id',
    AttributeType: 'S'
  }, {
    AttributeName: 'created_at',
    AttributeType: 'S'
  }, {
    AttributeName: 'average_rating',
    AttributeType: 'N'
  }],
  KeySchema: [{
    AttributeName: 'post_id',
    KeyType: 'HASH'
  }, {
    AttributeName: 'created_at',
    KeyType: 'RANGE'
  }],
  GlobalSecondaryIndexes: [{
    IndexName: 'parent_post_id-created_at-index',
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
      ReadCapacityUnits: 5,
      WriteCapacityUnits: 5
    },
    KeySchema: [{
      AttributeName: 'parent_post_id',
      KeyType: 'HASH'
    }, {
      AttributeName: 'created_at',
      KeyType: 'SORT'
    }],
    Projection: {
      ProjectionType: 'ALL'
    }
  }, {
    IndexName: 'parent_post_id-averge_rating-index',
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
      ReadCapacityUnits: 5,
      WriteCapacityUnits: 5
    },
    KeySchema: [{
      AttributeName: 'parent_post_id',
      KeyType: 'HASH'
    }, {
      AttributeName: 'average_rating',
      KeyType: 'SORT'
    }],
    Projection: {
      ProjectionType: 'ALL'
    }
  }],
  ProvisionedThroughput: {
    ReadCapacityUnits: 1,
    WriteCapacityUnits: 1
  }
};
```

Then I try to make a paginated query:

```
const paramsPosts = {
  TableName: this.table,
  IndexName: 'parent_post_id-created_at-index',
  KeyConditionExpression: '#parent_post_id = :parent_post_id',
  FilterExpression: '#resource_id = :resource_id',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#parent_post_id': 'parent_post_id',
    '#resource_id': 'resource_id',
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':parent_post_id': '-',
    ':resource_id': resource_id,
  },
  Limit: limit,
  ScanIndexForward: true,
  ExclusiveStartKey: lastEvaluatedKey
};
```

When I send a query with this values all is working:

```
{
  "resource_id": "VALID_RESOURCE_ID",
  "limit": 5
}
```

I got the next result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "posts": {
      "items": [
        {
          "comment": "This comment 1.",
          "created_at": "2018-07-31T19:40:21.899Z"
        },
        {
          "comment": "This comment 2.",
          "created_at": "2018-07-31T19:40:26.460Z"
        },
        {
          "comment": "This comment 3.",
          "created_at": "2018-07-31T19:40:30.810Z"
        },
        {
          "comment": "This comment 4.",
          "created_at": "2018-07-31T19:40:35.057Z"
        },
        {
          "comment": "This comment 5.",
          "created_at": "2018-07-31T19:40:39.341Z"
        }
      ],
      "summary": {
        "total_count": 13
      },
      "paging": {
        "next": {
          "post_id": "660b4878-e883-41ce-af4e-c393a20aac08",
          "created_at": "2018-07-31T19:40:39.341Z",
          "parent_post_id": "-"
        },
        "prev": null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here `data.posts.paging.next` is the `LastEvaluatedKey` that DynamoDB returns and when I try to use that value to paginate I got the following error:

```
{
  "data": {
    "posts": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The request processing has failed because of an unknown error, exception or failure.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "posts"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "message": "The request processing has failed because of an unknown error, exception or failure.",
          "code": "InternalFailure",
          "time": "2018-07-31T21:16:56.008Z",
          "requestId": "10dc5a07-a18e-407b-bba3-ad57506d5fd2",
          "statusCode": 500,
          "retryable": true,
          "stacktrace": [
            "InternalFailure: The request processing has failed because of an unknown error, exception or failure.",
            "    at Request.extractError (/home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)",
            "    at Request.callListeners (/home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)",
            "    at Request.emit (/home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)",
            "    at Request.emit (/home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
            "    at Request.transition (/home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
            "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
            "    at /home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
            "    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
            "    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)",
            "    at Request.callListeners (/home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have DynamoDB running in local inside of a Docker container with the InMemory flag set to true.

I thought that I only have to send GSI Key, that is composed by `parent_post_id` (partition key) and `created_at` (sort key) but reading in some places I found that I also have to send Table Key. If I remove `post_id` that is only part of Table Key I got the following error:

```
{
  "data": {
    "posts": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Exclusive Start Key must have same size as table's key schema",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "posts"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "message": "Exclusive Start Key must have same size as table's key schema",
          "code": "ValidationException",
          "time": "2018-07-31T21:20:11.286Z",
          "requestId": "f8961dcd-325c-4cda-8fa8-855539cae715",
          "statusCode": 400,
          "retryable": false,
          "stacktrace": [
            "ValidationException: Exclusive Start Key must have same size as table's key schema",
            "    at Request.extractError (/home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:48:27)",
            "    at Request.callListeners (/home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:105:20)",
            "    at Request.emit (/home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:77:10)",
            "    at Request.emit (/home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
            "    at Request.transition (/home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
            "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
            "    at /home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
            "    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
            "    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)",
            "    at Request.callListeners (/home/node/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:115:18)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT:

This is what DynamoDB prints in console:

```
dynamo-forum | Jul 31, 2018 9:32:31 PM com.almworks.sqlite4java.Internal log
dynamo-forum | WARNING: [sqlite] SQLiteDBAccess$20@268969a1: job exception
dynamo-forum | java.lang.NullPointerException
dynamo-forum |  at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.shared.access.sqlite.SQLiteDBAccessUtils.translateKeyAttributeValue(SQLiteDBAccessUtils.java:194)
dynamo-forum |  at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.shared.access.sqlite.SQLiteDBAccess$20.doWork(SQLiteDBAccess.java:2012)
dynamo-forum |  at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.shared.access.sqlite.SQLiteDBAccess$20.doWork(SQLiteDBAccess.java:1787)
dynamo-forum |  at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.shared.access.sqlite.AmazonDynamoDBOfflineSQLiteJob.job(AmazonDynamoDBOfflineSQLiteJob.java:97)
dynamo-forum |  at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteJob.execute(SQLiteJob.java:372)
dynamo-forum |  at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.executeJob(SQLiteQueue.java:534)
dynamo-forum |  at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.queueFunction(SQLiteQueue.java:667)
dynamo-forum |  at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.runQueue(SQLiteQueue.java:623)
dynamo-forum |  at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue.access$000(SQLiteQueue.java:77)
dynamo-forum |  at com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteQueue$1.run(SQLiteQueue.java:205)
dynamo-forum |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
dynamo-forum |
```

And this is by `AWS-SDK` using NPM package:

```
service-forum | [AWS dynamodb 500 0.025s 0 retries] query({ TableName: 'forum-post',
service-forum |   IndexName: 'parent_post_id-created_at-index',
service-forum |   KeyConditionExpression: '#parent_post_id = :parent_post_id',
service-forum |   FilterExpression: '#resource_id = :resource_id',
service-forum |   ExpressionAttributeNames:
service-forum |    { '#parent_post_id': 'parent_post_id',
service-forum |      '#resource_id': 'resource_id' },
service-forum |   ExpressionAttributeValues:
service-forum |    { ':parent_post_id': { S: '-' },
service-forum |      ':resource_id': { S: 'VALID_RESOURCE_ID' } },
service-forum |   Limit: 5,
service-forum |   ScanIndexForward: true,
service-forum |   ExclusiveStartKey:
service-forum |    { post_id: { S: '660b4878-e883-41ce-af4e-c393a20aac08' },
service-forum |      created_at: { S: '2018-07-31T19:40:39.341Z' },
service-forum |      parent_post_id: { S: '-' } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the KeySchema of the GlobalSecondaryIndex.

Instead of `KeyType: 'SORT'` it should be `KeyType: 'RANGE'`

AWS Documentation doesn't help much with this, as they always refer to it as `sort key` but you must declare the type as `range`.